# Mount LVM backup partition inside host on XEN

Tags: mount, lvm, xen

I have a XEN server (4.17) with a volume group `vg0` and some volumes on it where one is a logical volume especially for Nextcloud e.g.:

```
lvcreate -n nextcloud -L2000G vg0
mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg0/nextcloud
```

These are my volumes:

```
# lvs                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  LV                              VG  Attr         LSize   Pool Origin                 Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert 
  nextcloud                       vg0 -wi-ao----   2,01t                                                                     
  root                            vg0 -wi-ao----  10,00g                                                                     
  swap                            vg0 -wi-ao----   4,00g                                                                     
  vm01-disk                       vg0 -wi-a----- 580,00g   
  vm01-swap                       vg0 -wi-a-----   8,00g
```

The nextcloud partition `/dev/mapper/vg0-nextcloud` is only visible inside the Dom0 VM.

How do I expose the `nextcloud` partition to vm01 so I can use it as storage for Nextcloud there?

I want to use the folder `/var/www/nextcloud/html/data` to be located on vg0-nextcloud.

Comment: If you want to present the logical volume `vg0-nextcloud` to the VM, you will need to unmount it on dom0, or else the unsynchronized caches between the dom0 and the VM will cause filesystem corruption (unless you have set up a cluster filesystem between the host and VM, which would be unusual). If you need to access the LV in both host & VM, you should export it as a NFS share on the host and mount that share on the VM.

Comment: Or I create a snapshot of the LVM and mount that read only (for backups)

Comment: If you present only the snapshot device to the `vm01` and mount it there as a simple filesystem, that's fine. But if you present the physical volume containing the `nextcloud` LV and its snapshot, and try activating only the snapshot in `vm01`, caching may still eat your data: as the `dom0` keeps updating the main LV, the snapshot metadata keeps getting updates as the "old" data is dynamically moved from the main LV to the snapshot LV as it gets overwritten on the main LV side. **But if the `vm01` thinks it's in control of the entire VG, it may rely on stale snapshot metadata in cache.**

Comment: yes, sure. Mounting a snapshot as productive filesystem is a bad idea. I only mount the snapshot temporary for backup purposes and discard the snapshot, when done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add  the disk entry to your xen host in ex.

```
/etc/xen/vm01.cfg
```

like so

```
disk = ['phy:/dev/vg0/nextcloud,xvda3,w']
```

reboot your vm and add it to `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/xvda3   /var/www/nextcloud/html/data   ext4    defaults    0   2
```